# Node.js is missing libatomic.so.1?

Tags: software-installation, node.js, shared-libraries

I've installed node.js on my rPi2 using nvm (following [this](https://www.losant.com/blog/how-to-install-nodejs-on-raspberry-pi) guide, but updated to the latest LTS version of node) and it seems to have partially installed. The issue seems to be that node cannot find a library called `libatomic.so.1`. Because it couldn't find this library, nvm seems to have also not added node to `PATH`, but the right files seem to be there. Does anyone know a fix?

```sh
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ nvm --version
0.35.3
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ nvm ls
       v14.17.1
default -> v14.17.1
node -> stable (-> v14.17.1) (default)
stable -> 14.17 (-> v14.17.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> v14.17.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.17.1
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ nvm alias default v14.17.1
default -> v14.17.1
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node
bash: node: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node
/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Personally, I use [nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) to install nodejs, which then lets me keep it up to date using `apt update; apt upgrade`